# List of Apps for Organisation / Repository via GraphQL

Tags: graphql, github-api

I am using GraphQL extensively to peruse GitHub's data structures.   For example, this will give me back a list of collaborators for a repo:

```
{
  repository(name: "spring-bot", owner: "finos") {
    id
    collaborators {
      edges {
        permission
        node {
          id
          email
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I would like to do is augment this list with the **apps** or **bots** being used by a repo / organisation, but I don't see any documentation around this.

Is this something that exists, or a feature that's being worked on?

thanks!